# How can I rotate 2 objects based on connection points?

Tags: unity, quaternion

I have 2 objects, each with GameObject children which are empty objects that I call snap points.  These snap points represent where the original objects can connect together.  They are positioned to that transform.forward faces outwards from the object.

I am trying to make simple code that will rotate and position a 2nd object so that the desired snap points connect.

My mostly functioning code:

```
public class ProcPlacable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("The points this object can connect to another snap point.")]
    public List<GameObject> snapPoints;

    // This positions go so that the plug fits into the socket.
    // Plug: The snap point on the go.
    // Socket: The snap point on the object it is connecting to.
    public void AttachObjectToSnapPoint(GameObject go, GameObject plug, GameObject socket)
    {
        // Rotate for alignment
        go.transform.rotation = plug.transform.rotation * socket.transform.rotation;
        go.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 180);
        //go.transform.rotation = plug.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(socket.transform.rotation);
        //go.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 180);
        // Slot into place
        Vector3 rotatedOffset = go.transform.rotation * plug.transform.localPosition;
        go.transform.position = socket.transform.position - rotatedOffset;
    }
}
```

My code for testing:

````
public class SnapCorrectly : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pierPrefab;
    public float rotateBy = 10f;
    public int plugIndex = 1;
    public int socketIndex = 1;
    public GameObject plugMarker;
    public GameObject socketMarker;

    private GameObject connectedPier;
    private ProcPlacable placable;
    private ProcPlacable connectedPlacable;
    private float angle = 0f;
    private int watch;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        placable = gameObject.GetComponent<ProcPlacable>();
        ReplaceConnected();
    }

    public void ReplaceConnected()
    {
        plugMarker.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        socketMarker.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        if (connectedPier != null)
        {
            Destroy(connectedPier);
        }
        connectedPier = GameObject.Instantiate(pierPrefab);
        connectedPlacable = connectedPier.GetComponent<ProcPlacable>();
        GameObject plug = connectedPlacable.snapPoints[plugIndex];
        GameObject socket = placable.snapPoints[socketIndex];
        placable.AttachObjectToSnapPoint(connectedPier, plug, socket);
        plugMarker.gameObject.transform.parent = plug.transform;
        plugMarker.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        socketMarker.gameObject.transform.parent = socket.transform;
        socketMarker.gameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        watch = plugIndex + socketIndex;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            angle += rotateBy;
            Debug.Log("New Angle: " + angle);
            gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotateBy);
            ReplaceConnected();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            angle -= rotateBy;
            Debug.Log("New Angle: " + angle);
            gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotateBy);
            ReplaceConnected();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            socketIndex = (socketIndex - 1 + placable.snapPoints.Count) % placable.snapPoints.Count;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            socketIndex = (socketIndex + 1) % placable.snapPoints.Count;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            plugIndex = (plugIndex - 1 + connectedPlacable.snapPoints.Count) % connectedPlacable.snapPoints.Count;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            plugIndex = (plugIndex + 1) % connectedPlacable.snapPoints.Count;
        }
        if (watch != plugIndex + socketIndex)
        {
            ReplaceConnected();
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: You have an extra degree of freedom here, which is rotation around the "out" axis. (If your objects were connected with a straight cylindrical peg, this would be like twisting them around that peg). Should we use the up axis of the snap points to align the two on this remaining axis, or just minimize the rotation delta from where then object had been, or do you have a different preferred policy for setting this degree of freedom?

Comment: I am making the assumption that 'up' is always Vector3.up.  This is for assembling prefabs for a level.  All assets I have (and all I ever expect to get) will be oriented with the same up vector.